# Method in Mock service is called but the toHaveBeenCalled() fails in Angular Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test if the mock service method is called by method in component.When I used
console.log() inside the method logOut() [Method inside the service] it printed in the console but the
test fails

Method in **header.component.ts**

onLogOut()

{

```
 this.authenticationService.logOut();
```

}

File **header.component.spec.ts**

```
@Injectable()
class MockAuthService extends AuthenticationService {

user$ = of(new User('R-234', 'Alex', '23@gmail.com'));

logOut() {
 console.log('Logged Out');
 }
}
```

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {

```
let component: HeaderComponent;
let authService: AuthenticationService;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [HttpClient, AuthenticationService, MockAuthService],
  }).compileComponents();

   TestBed.overrideComponent(HeaderComponent, {
    set: {
      providers: [
         { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthService },
    ],
  },
   });
 });

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   authService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
  });


   it('should call logOut method once in the service', fakeAsync(() => {

    let spy = spyOn(authService, 'logOut').and.callThrough();
    component.onLogOut();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);//this fails
    }));
  });
```

Comment: Can you try to create the spy this way? let spy = spyOn(authService, 'logOut');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the `overrideComponent`, I think that could be causing the issue of getting the proper handle of the `AuthenticationService`.

You should directly `useClass` in the `TestBed` for the mock.

```
let component: HeaderComponent;
let authService: AuthenticationService;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [HttpClient, AuthenticationService, 
        // add this line
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthService }
    ],
  }).compileComponents();

 });

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   authService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
  });


   it('should call logOut method once in the service', fakeAsync(() => {

      let spy = spyOn(authService, 'logOut').and.callThrough();
      component.onLogOut();

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);//this fails
    }));
  });
```